# Create a page using form input

Tags: php

I have constructed a site for users to upload their own work and share it.

At the moment, people can search the database for pieces of work and they can upload their own which is working fine.

However, when someone uploads a piece of work I have to manually duplicate a php page, add the url into the database and edit the query to show the relevant content.

I was wondering if there was any way of getting my php file to do this for each upload.

Thanks, Tyler

Comment: It's a real hassle to do that every time. Why don't you give them all ID's and then have one page that `echo`'s out that ID's information from the database?

Comment: That is essentially what each individual page does. But, my problem is that users click a link from on the search results page to the page with the piece of work on and I am not sure if there is a way of having the ID change depending on what link they click on.

Comment: Yeah, but instead of hundreds of individual pages, you could have only 1 page and it would still be the same! That way, if you have a design change/wording change, you need to do it once, not hundreds of times. and do a loop and include something like `<href='link.php?id=4'>` where `id` is relative to the work someone uploads.